# How to disable EF .net core2 api from retrieving navigation properties

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I've created the dbcontext and models using EF pomelo.entityframeworkcore.mysql, I want to figure out how to disable the context from retrieving uncessary information while trying to fetch objects that have foriegnkey relationships with other tables. 
right now the api returns objects and their related object through the foreignkey navigation.

for example this is what it returns : 
[image]

and this is how I want to return it: 
[image]

I want it to stop at the serviceextra for example. its an Icollection variable inside the Service. since service and extra both have a third table of many to many relationship.

Possible cause: in the function I retrieve three objects, after I retrieve the Service

```
Service = await _context.Service.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Idservice == id);
```

I retrieve another object called ServiceExtra, now service has serviceextra navigation field, so I do call this function

```
var serviceExtras = await _context.ServiceExtra.Where(m => m.Fkservice == id).ToListAsync();
```

it also fills the data inside serviceExtra of the Service object. if I do not call this function it doesn't.

Startup class :

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration,IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {

        Configuration = configuration;
        HostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;

    }
    public  IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        var connection = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:connection"];
        services.AddDbContext<Db_context>(options => options.UseMySql(connection));
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseMvc();

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have Lazy Loading enabled? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: The only *reliable* way of controlling the *exact* data to be returned is to use DTOs / ViewModels and projection (`Select`) queries.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I enabled the lazy loading according to the documentation but for some reason when the EF generated the models it didn't define the navigation properties as virtual , so now it throws this error : UseLazyLoadingProxies requires all entity types to be public, unsealed, have virtual navigation properties, and have a public or protected constructor.

Comment: I was suggesting that Lazy Loading might be the _cause_ of your problem, not the _solution_.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I found a possible reason why this happens, please take a look at the edit if you dont mind.

Comment: Yep.  The Change Tracker will "fix up" relationships between tracked objects when loaded separately.

Comment: What to do in this situation then?

Comment: @Foghunt Please share your startup class code.

Comment: @TanvirArjel added

Comment: @Foghunt Can you give team viewer id and pass. I can solve your problem!

Comment: @TanvirArjel Can't u just post how to solve it here?

Comment: No! Actually I needed to see other configurations too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179137/discussion-between-foghunt-and-tanvirarjel).